# Bulk insert from Array in mongodb JavaScript console

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to make a bulk insert from the MongoDB console of an array into a collection.

I'd like to do something similar to this.

> obj1 = {_id:ObjectId(),blabla:1};
>
> obj2 = {_id:ObjectId(),blabla:2};
>
> objs  = [obj1, obj2];
>
> db.test.insert(objs);
>
> db.test.find()
>
> > {"_id": ObjectId("xxxx"), "blabla": 1}
>    > {"_id": ObjectId("xxxx"), "blabla": 2}

But, instead of inserting two objects on the collection, it stores one list with the two objects.

> db.test.find()
>
> > {"_id": ObjectId("xxx"), "0":{"_id": ObjectId("xxxx"), "blabla": 1}, "1":{"_id": ObjectId("xxxx"), "blabla": 2} }

That functionality appears to present on other drivers (like [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.4%2B/api/pymongo/collection.html)), but I can't find a way of doing that from the mongodb console, in JavaScript code.

Answer (score 13):

The feature to insert multiple documents into a collection has been added to Mongo command shell version 2.1+. Now You can insert and array of documents into your collection.

Example:

```
db.users.insert([{name:'Jon', email:'Jon_Doe@mail.com'},{name:'Jane', email:'Jane_Doe@mail.com'}])
```

For more information look at these jira closed feature request:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3819

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2395

Answer (score 2):

There is an existing feature request for this. http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2429

Answer (score 1):

```
objs.forEach(function(obj) { db.test.insert(obj) });
```

Answer (score 1):

Bulk is available in 2.6.6.

```
var bulk=db.posts.initializeUnorderedBulkOp() ;
bulk.insert(obj1) ; bulk.insert(obj2);...

bulk.execute() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do a bulk insert through the interactive command shell. But there is a commandline tool that ships with Mongo that allows you to import multiple records as either JSON (your best option), CSV or Binary.

```
> mongoimport -h <host> -d <database> -c <collection> -u <user> -p <password> --file <input file> --jsonArray
```

The `jsonArray` flag will allow you to insert multiple records when you use the json array file. Another important note is to make sure you have the file ending with a new line character. Otherwise the last line will not be parsed.